# Package ratpack.test does not exist

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, ratpack

I have a Gradle, Intellij-idea project and I'm using ratpack. I'm trying to use the ratpack.test library to test my API however it cannot seem to find the ratpack.test package.

When compiling it says package ratpack.test does not exist.

Gradle: io.ratpack:ratpack-test 1.7.5 is in my external libraries and module.

Upon the error if I hover over the ratpack.test import it says add library 'Gradle: io.ratpack:ratpack-test 1.7.5' to classpath which I click. Then when I try to build again it breaks with the same error.

build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.ratpack:ratpack-gradle:1.7.5"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'MIR.Interviwer.API'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: "io.ratpack.ratpack-java"
apply plugin: "idea"

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2:1.4.199"
}

ratpack.baseDir = file('ratpack')
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is if you are attempting to import the Ratpack test classes in your `main` module, where they are not available (after all, they are test classes and are only available in the `test` module).

Just as a heads up, you are also using deprecated configurations. So unless you are in a legacy project with an old version, use these instead:

- `testCompile` -> `testImplementation`
- `compile` -> `implementation`
- `runtime` -> `runtimeOnly`

You can also get rid of the entire `buildscript` block and the `apply plugin: "io.ratpack.ratpack-java"` line, and just type:

```
plugins {
  id "io.ratpack.ratpack-java" version "1.7.5"
}
```

Comment: Thanks tided up the build file! Do you know how I'd go about fixing the problem you stated in your opening paragraph? First time using Java/Gradle!

Comment: Are the classes into which you're trying to import `ratpack.test` in `src/main/java` or `src/test/java`, @ARedfearn?

Comment: @kris they're in src/main/java

Comment: Yep you're right just tried to build in src/test/java and it works... naive mistake by me. Thanks for the help!